# EJB global exception handler

Tags: java, exception, ejb

I need to add global exception handler to my project for catching all uncaught exception in the EGB container.

I have read about the method that uses new threads to catch the uncaught exceptions but that will not be help me.

is there is any other ideas out there for EJBs ??

Comment: Hello how did you finally do to achieve your goal?

Answer (score 2):

There are no API:s for globally handling exceptions afaik, but have you considered using an [interceptor](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/tutorial/interceptor/interceptor.html) for this?

The interceptor class:

```
package test;

import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;


public class Interceptor {

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object exceptionHandler(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        try {
            return ctx.proceed();
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            // Do something with the exception
            throw re;
        }
    }
}
```

The default interceptor mapping in ejb-jar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor>
            <interceptor-class>test.Interceptor</interceptor-class>
        </interceptor>
    </interceptors>
    <assembly-descriptor>
        <interceptor-binding>
            <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
            <interceptor-class>test.Interceptor</interceptor-class>
        </interceptor-binding>
    </assembly-descriptor>
</ejb-jar>
```